# What will happen if TCP sending buffer is full when I use Python Twisted Framework?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to write my own "TCP over UDP" protocol with twisted. I want my protocol to behave exactly same as the TCP protocol in this scenario.

So what is the standard behavior for Twisted TCP protocol when the sending buffer is full?

Thanks.

Comment: "UDP over TCP" sound like all the disadvantages of UDP plus all the disadvantages of TCP. What exactly should it be?

Comment: @KlausD. It's "TCP over UDP", typo here. It's a experimental personal project which intent to optimize some bad network connection.

Comment: I wrote a demo code and have a test. And I got a "MemoryError". Seems that the sending buffer is "infinite", you will use up all your memory if you keep sending data to an unresponsive peer.